# CRUD either edit or delete work, together will fail

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am developing a CRUD function based on bootstrap and php. If click edit button, popup windows will be shown and data can edit and update. If click delete button, popup windows will be shown with data but only allow to confirm delete . I dont know why if run it individually only contains one part of code, the program is running properly. But if put both functions code together, only edit function work, and delete function will not shown any data in the popup windows. Also it is strange that when click confirm delete, it is not direct to delete sql statement (delcatsql.php), but direct to update sql(editcatsql.php). Can advice what is wrong?? Thanks!

```
**manage_categories.php**

<tbody> 
    <?php
    require_once 'source/db_connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
     $i=0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i = $i + 1;
    ?>
    
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['catid']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['catname']; ?>  </td>
                <td> <button type="button" id="editcatbtn" class="btn btn-primary 
editcatbtn">edit</button>  </td>
                <td> <button type="button" id="delcatbtn" class="btn btn-danger delcatbtn" 
>Delete</button>  </td>
                        
                </tr>   
                
    <?php       }
        }
    ?>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(' .delcatbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#delcatmodel').modal('show');
         $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
             var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
             }).get();
             console.log(data);
             $('#catid').val(data[0]);
            $('#catname').val(data[1]); 
});
});
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(' .editcatbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#editcatmodel').modal('show');
         $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
             var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
             }).get();
             console.log(data);
            bootstrap
             $('#catid').val(data[0]);
            $('#catname').val(data[1]); 
});
});
</script>
            
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php
//Categpry Form
include_once("editcatmodel.php");
include_once("delcatmodel.php");
include_once("editcategory.php");
 ?>
</body>


**editcatmodel.php**
<!-- edit Model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editcatmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Edit Category</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <form action="editcatsql.php" method="POST">
  
 
  <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="hidden" name="editcatid" id="catid">
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="editcatname" id="catname" class="form-control">
      </div>

  </div>
  
  
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" name="editcategory" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- /.modal -->


editcatsql.php
<?php
include_once 'source/session.php';
require_once 'source/db_connect.php';
?>
<?php
 $username = 'root';
password = '';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pos';
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pos");

if (isset($_POST['editcategory'])) {
    $tempcatname = $_POST[('editcatname')];
    $tempcatid = $_POST[('editcatid')];

// write edit query
$sql = "UPDATE category SET catname='$tempcatname' WHERE catid='$tempcatid'" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(! $result )
{
            die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    header('location: manage_categories.php');
}
?>

**delcatmodel.php**
<!-- Delete Model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delcatmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Confirm Delete Category?</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <form action="delcatsql.php" method="POST">
  
 
  <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="hidden" name="delcatid" id="catid">
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="delcatname" id="catname" class="form-control" disabled>
      </div>

  </div>
  
  
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" name="deletecategory" class="btn btn-primary">Delete2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

delcatsql.php
<?php

 include_once 'source/session.php';

 require_once 'source/db_connect.php';
?>


<?php


 $username = 'root';
 $password = '';
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pos';
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pos");

if (isset($_POST['deletecategory'])) {

$tempcatname = $_POST[('delcatname')];
$tempcatid = $_POST[('delcatid')];
        
// write delete query
//$sql = "delete from category where catid='$tempcatid'" ;

$sql = "delete from category where catid='$tempcatid'" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(! $result )
{
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
        header('location: manage_categories.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: You have an error. [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) worked only for the old API. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Dharman. Thanks for reply. But its looks like the problem happening in my program is not related to this. Actually, I am not sure the problem is due to duplicate value name that pass from 2 different on click event or duplicate ID, name issue. Its too strange that  if I remove either editcatbtn or delcatbtn script, and remove the related popup windows modal file, the function work perfect. but keep both , only delete function not behaviour as expected. Anyone can help??

Comment: I think I got idea. it looks like the below  code is read from sequence. If I move delcatmodal.php in 1st line, edit function 2nd line, then del function is work, and edit function is not work. So, any idea how to deal with this? can I add below code to jquery on click event ? o
<?php>
include_once("editcatmodel.php");
include_once("delcatmodel.php");
 ?>